# Wordpress - Will changes in permalink automatically changes my existing post

Tags: wordpress, permalink

I'm using *Wordress* platform. For a future post I want to change the permalink setting from:

`blog.com/2016/02/my-post`

to

`blog.com/my-post`

Will it automatically change my existing posts (old) permalinks too?

or will they remain the same?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Questions about wordpress.com belong on [WebApps.SE]. Questions about installing and maintaining WordPress belong on [WordPress.SE]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Wordpress there is a default permalink structure for all posts. If you change that you will change the permalink for each and every post (past and future ones).

However you **can change** the *permalink* of a *single post* and keep previous posts on the default structure. You need to do this:

1. Go to the post.
2. Above the content, where it says *Permalink*, click the *Edit* button. (*)
3. Type in your new permalink for this post.
4. Hit enter.

(*) Your permalink structure must be set to  “Post Name” in `Settings -> Permalinks` to have this option.

Wordpress creates a redirect from the old permalink to the new one. Both of them will exist.